# Java: How to remove default KeyStrokes from any JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, key-bindings, keystroke

I want to control which keystroke belong to which `Jcomponent`. I even want to get how to remove the default keystrokes associated with a `Jcomponent` and replace them with other favourite  keystrokes.

I followed this oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto), it gives an example with JButton, I tried it and it works fine, but when I try it with [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) it doesn’t work!

What exactly I tried is removing the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key, that is prevent the JComponent from responding to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> presses

I used this code to remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key:

```
firstButton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "none");
```

The same thing for JComboBox

```
sizesComboBox.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "none");
```

But doesn’t work, that it is (JComboBox) still respond to the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key

For the `firstButton` that I removed the effect of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> presses; I added the key <kbd>F</kbd>, So that now the `firstButton` is pressed when you press the <kbd>F</kbd> key on the keyboard, ant not respond to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (intended). Note that presses of <kbd>F</kbd> take place even if `firstButton` doesn’t have the focus (`JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`)

This is a SSCCE code showing my example:
*Note*: I intentionally didn’t add the line of code above to the second button "secondButton" so it is still respond to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> by default.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyStrokeTest extends JPanel
{

    JPanel widgetPanel;
    JPanel textAreaPanel;
    JButton firstButton;
    JButton secondButton;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JComboBox<Integer> sizesComboBox;

    public KeyStrokeTest()
    {
        firstButton = new JButton("First");
        firstButton.addActionListener(eventWatcher);
        firstButton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "none");
        firstButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F"), "F Key");
        firstButton.getActionMap().put("F Key", eventWatcher);

        secondButton = new JButton("Second");
        secondButton.addActionListener(eventWatcher);

        sizesComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        sizesComboBox.addItemListener(new itemListenerClass());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            sizesComboBox.addItem(i);
        }
        sizesComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        sizesComboBox.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "none");


        textArea = new JTextArea(0, 0);
        JScrollPane scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        widgetPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        widgetPanel.add(firstButton);
        widgetPanel.add(secondButton);
        widgetPanel.add(sizesComboBox);

        textAreaPanel.add(scrollTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, textAreaPanel, widgetPanel);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(280);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(.5d);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(splitPane);
    }
    AbstractAction eventWatcher = new AbstractAction()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            Object source = ae.getSource();
            if (source == firstButton)
            {
                textArea.append("First button clicked\n");
            }
            if (source == secondButton)
            {
                textArea.append("Second button clicked\n");
            }
        }
    };

    private class itemListenerClass implements ItemListener
    {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == sizesComboBox)
            {
                if (textArea != null)
                {
                    textArea.append("Item " + sizesComboBox.getSelectedItem() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyStroke Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.add(new KeyStrokeTest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**The reason** why I want to control over default keystrokes for JComponent is because I want to remove the default effect of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> on all the JComponent, except one button that will respond to the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> presses, wherever the focus is on, using `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, so that clicking another component (and moving the focus away from the excepted button) will not prevent the effect of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> on that button.

---

**Another point**: If you tested the code above, you will notice that selecting an item from the JComboBox poduces two lines of, if you select item "4" the output in the JTextArea is

> ```
> Item 4
> Item 4
> ```

Why two??

Thanks.

Comment: Assigning the key stroke to a new name many not unregistered those bindings that already exist (or it has registered). You might like to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041277/how-to-prevent-jscrollpane-arrow-key-handling-from-moving-caret-when-scroll-pane/12044715#12044715) for some hints, but your going to need to know the name of the key binding used by the look and feel to get it to work

Comment: to `Another point:` ItemListener firing always two event, have to determine is SELECTED/DESELECTED

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But doesn't work, that it is (JComboBox) still respond to the SPACE
>   key

You should use the `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` `InputMap` like so (As you may notice I make use of `KeyEvent` and `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int key,int modifier,boolean onRelease)` as its more readable and less prone to mistakes i.e typing the wrong string argument etc.):

```
sizesComboBox.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,0,false), "none");
```

The reason for this as far as I see is explained nicely [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps):

> The component contains (or is) the component that has the focus. This
>   input map is commonly used for a composite component — a component
>   whose implementation depends on child components. For example, `JTable`s
>   make all their bindings using `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` so
>   that if the user is editing, the *up-arrow* key (for example) still
>   changes the selected cell.

So I deduce `JCombobox` is a composite component and thus we need the correct `InputMap` - `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`, to remove all its inner components KeyBinding functionality for a specific key i.e <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

> Another point: If you tested the code above, you will notice that
>   selecting an item from the `JComboBox` poduces two lines of, if you
>   select item "4" the output in the `JTextArea` is
>
> ```
> Item 4
> Item 4
> ```
>
> Why two??

As said by @mKorbel (+1 to his comment) there are 2 events which can occur:

- an item is deselected
- an item is selected

These events, occur in pairs as when we select a new value the old one is deselected. Thus we must check for this and act appropriately:

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
   if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) { 
       //am item was selected do something
   }
}
```

**Other suggestions:**

- Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame`.
- Use an appropriate `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize` to return `Dimension`s which fit the contents and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting is visible and after adding components.