# Java: Call original key action after override

Tags: java, swing, action, key-bindings, keyevent

For a Text-Editor I'm developing I have overriden the default Action to the HOME-key. However in some cases I would still like to make use of the original HOME action (to jump to the beginning of the line). How can I fire this original action?

Example-code:

```
//Add the homekey and its action to the text-editor:
Key homeKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("HOME");
editor.getInputMap().put(homeKey, new HomeCommand()); 
...

private class HomeCommand extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if(doSomethingSpecial())
            performSpecialHomeAction();
        else
            performRegularHomeAction(); //How to get the regular action??
    }
}
```

Note: I'm looking for the elegant solution, I'd prefer not to write my own version of the HomeKey-Action.

I have googled and tried several approaches, none of them worked:

- Action a = area.getActionMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("HOME"));
  Resulted in null.
- Simulate pressing the Home Key via the Robot class. That however just fires my own custom Action.

Comment: Have you tried super.performRegularHomeAction();  ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That function does not exist. If you look at the code you'll see I'm replacing the normal HomeAction-Class

Comment: Why don't you have a reference of regularHomeAction before putting a `HomeCommand`?

Comment: How would I get that? The following: 
Action a = area.getActionMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("HOME")); results in null.

Comment: If I look at the code I can't see `performSpecialHomeAction` at all, but hay.  You might need to extract the existing `Action` from the `InputMap` before you override it and then call it directly...`oldAction.actionPerformed(ev)` for example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer something like my answer xD?

Comment: @MadProgrammer is this [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12044715/2415194)

Comment: @nachokk That's a pretty good catch! `caret-begin-line` would be the key command that would be required based on that example... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a reference in your `HomeCommand`.

```
class HomeCommand extends AbstractAction {

 private final Action action;

    public HomeCommand(Action action){
         this.action=action;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if(doSomethingSpecial())
            performSpecialHomeAction();
        else
            action.actionPerformed(ev); 
    }
}
```

Then when you create it.

```
KeyStroke homeKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("HOME");
InputMap inputMap = editor.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap actionMap = editor.getActionMap();
Action action = actionMap.get("caret-begin-line");
inputMap.put(homeKey, "caret-begin-line"); 
actionMap.put("caret-begin-line", new HomeCommand(action));
```

Comment: That would be perfect, however: 
Action action = actionMap.get(inputMap.get(homeKey));

Returns null.

Comment: Then you don't have an action associated to that component with "HOME"

Comment: Exactly, I don't. I want the regular action that would happen when you normally press HOME, i.e. jumping to the beginning of the line.